# justify-content is not applying in chakra ui

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm developing a Website using Next.js and Chakra-ui. Here I'm tring to align the ButtonGroup to the end. For that I'm trying to use `justifyContent="space-between"` but itsnt working.
Here is the code for the Card Components

```
            <Flex direction="column" px={0} justifyContent="space-between">
                <Flex px={10} pt={10} direction="column" lineHeight="7" mb={5}>
                    <Heading size="sm">{data.name}</Heading>
                    <UnorderedList mt={5}>
                        {data.features.map((element, index) => (<ListItem key={index} fontSize="13px">{element}</ListItem>))}
                    </UnorderedList>
                </Flex>
                <ButtonGroup spacing="0">
                    <Button w="100%" m={0} borderRadius="0 0 0 20px" fontSize="14px">
                        Explore More
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        w="100%"
                        color="white"
                        bg="#274E85"
                        m={0}
                        borderRadius="0 0 20px 0"
                        fontSize="14px"
                    >
                        Apply Now
                    </Button>
                </ButtonGroup>

            </Flex>
```

Please Someone help me solve this
[image]

Comment: Add flexGrow=1 to your main flex, or try height: 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add flexGrow=1 to your main flex, or try height: 100%

answer by [@Sephyre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10375171/sephyre)

Answer (score 2):

Well in my case I was writing `d=flex`, and replacing it with `display=flex` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the similar issue with chakra ui.
My code in which justifyContent was not working is as below

```
<Box d="flex" justifyContent="space-between" w="100%" h="91.5vh" p="10px">
      {user && <MyChats/>}
      {user && <ChatBox/>}
</Box>
```

I simply changed d="flex" to display="flex" and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest if space between is not working in chakra ui then u can apply it manually.. like just give it classname and do manually

Answer (score 0):

So, the spacer doesn't work in a column oriented Flex, just row.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing d="flex" write in full, Don't write in shorthand

For example
<Box display="flex" justifyContent={"space-between"} w={"100"} h={"91.5"} p={"10"} >

....

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue. You should specifiy width of child elements. not by percentage

Answer (score -2):

You should not use `justifyContent`, but instead, you should only use `justify`.